# Как убрать эту(смотрите скрины) полосу, которая находится снизу страницы?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, html-form

Вот вид страницы:
[image]
Вроде, всё в порядке. Но! Справа можно заметить полосу прокрутки, и если мы прокрутим вниз, то увидим эту полосу:
[image]
Так вот, как её убрать, чтобы страница приобрела <a href="[image]">такой вид, но уже без полосы прокрутки?
Вот мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inst-Post Searcher</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #2a2929;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 20%, #2a2929 90%, #808080);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#333), to(#808080), color-stop(0.5, #2a2929));
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333', endColorstr='#808080');
            background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
        }

        .new {
            color: darkorange;
            text-decoration: none;
            top: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <nobr><h1 style="color: darkorange;">Inst-Post Searcher</h1></nobr>
        <hr size="2" color="darkorange" />
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <div style="left: 32.5%; text-align: center; font-size: 1.0vw; color: darkorange; background: none; border: none;">
            <hr style="position: absolute; top: 90%; width: 99%" size="5" color="#000000" />
            <nobr><a style="position: absolute; top: 95%; left: 33%" class="new" href='@Url.Page("/TermsOfUse")'>Условия использования</a></nobr>
            <nobr><a style="position: absolute; top: 95%; left: 43.5%" class="new" href='@Url.Page("/PrivacyPolicy")'>Политика конфиденциальности</a></nobr>
            <nobr><a style="position: absolute; top: 95%; left: 57.5%" class="new" href='@Url.Page("/DeveloperContacts")'>Контакты разработчика</a></nobr>
        </div>
    </form>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Только без критики, пожалуйста! Вот чётко поставленный вопрос: как убрать эту полосу?

Comment: как совет полностью перепиши вопрос и стили своего футера(как я понял это футер хотя ты его никак не обозначил что является ошибкой, ты сделал его формой) и можно стили не инлайново прописать, убери топ95%)

Comment: и на чем ты пишешь, что такое <nobr>

Comment: мой личный совет, переверстай все как нужно, сделай футер не формой а секцией с `display: flex`

Comment: А что такое `@RenderBody()`? Может, оно что-то добавляет (не знаю, что) что создаёт эту полосу?

Answer (score 0):

У вас размер тела - 1332х937, а размер всей страницы - 1348х937. Если в блоке body увеличить background-size до 100% 103%, то получается так как вы хотите.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inst-Post Searcher</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #2a2929;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 20%, #2a2929 90%, #808080);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#333), to(#808080), color-stop(0.5, #2a2929));
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333', endColorstr='#808080');
            background-size: 100% 103%;
        }
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
        }

        .new {
            color: darkorange;
            text-decoration: none;
            top: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <nobr><h1 style="color: darkorange;">Inst-Post Searcher</h1></nobr>
        <hr size="2" color="darkorange" />
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <div style="left: 32.5%; text-align: center; font-size: 1.0vw; color: darkorange; background: none; border: none;">
            <hr style="position: absolute; top: 90%; width: 99%" size="5" color="#000000" />
            <nobr><a style="position: absolute; top: 95%; left: 33%" class="new" href='@Url.Page("/TermsOfUse")'>Условия использования</a></nobr>
            <nobr><a style="position: absolute; top: 95%; left: 43.5%" class="new" href='@Url.Page("/PrivacyPolicy")'>Политика конфиденциальности</a></nobr>
            <nobr><a style="position: absolute; top: 95%; left: 57.5%" class="new" href='@Url.Page("/DeveloperContacts")'>Контакты разработчика</a></nobr>
        </div>
    </form>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Но вообще на мой взгляд вам бы лучше высоту всей страницы чуть-чуть уменьшить